# Webdriver logs for Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, selenium, logging, selenium-webdriver

Both [`Chrome`](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver) and [`PhantomJS`](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/#git%2Fpy%2Fselenium%2Fwebdriver%2Fphantomjs) selenium drivers can log everything that is going on the browser side. By specifying the service log path while initializing the driver, you can control where the logs would be written to. E.g. for chrome (in Python):

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service_log_path="/tmp/log")
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
driver.close()
```

After executing the code, `/tmp/log` file would contain the service logs which is helpful for debugging:

```
[0.985][INFO]: Launching chrome: ...
[2.620][INFO]: RESPONSE InitSession {
   "acceptSslCerts": true,
   "applicationCacheEnabled": false,
   "browserConnectionEnabled": false,
   "browserName": "chrome",
   "chrome": {
      "userDataDir": "/var/folders/yy/ppdg927x4zv8b0rbzg1f_jzh0000gn/T/.org.chromium.Chromium.ibsof9"
   },
   "cssSelectorsEnabled": true,
   "databaseEnabled": false,
   "handlesAlerts": true,
   "javascriptEnabled": true,
   "locationContextEnabled": true,
   "nativeEvents": true,
   "platform": "Mac OS X",
   "rotatable": false,
   "takesHeapSnapshot": true,
   "takesScreenshot": true,
   "version": "37.0.2062.120",
   "webStorageEnabled": true
}
[2.677][INFO]: Waiting for pending navigations...
[2.696][INFO]: Done waiting for pending navigations
[3.290][INFO]: Waiting for pending navigations...
[4.338][INFO]: Done waiting for pending navigations
[4.338][INFO]: RESPONSE Navigate
[4.339][INFO]: COMMAND CloseWindow {

}
[4.451][INFO]: RESPONSE CloseWindow
```

Is there a way to get the same information but using `Firefox` web driver?

From what I see in the source code, both `Chrome` and `PhantomJS` fire up [new services](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/py/selenium/webdriver/chrome/service.py) via `subprocess` and pass the `--log-path` argument to it. And these services are responsible for the logging. As for [`Firefox` driver](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/py/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py), it's implementation is quite different and is based on [`FirefoxBinary`](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/py/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py) class.

Provided example and links are Python-related, but the question is pretty much generic and language-agnostic. Would appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to set logging options in firefox profile as in developer tips link - https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/DeveloperTips - for console log you should use:

```
FirefoxProfile p = new FirefoxProfile();
p.setPreference("webdriver.log.file", "/tmp/firefox_console");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(p);
```

For browser log, you should use

```
webdriver.firefox.logfile
```

(https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FirefoxDriver)

Hope this helps.

Comment: The log file is not as detailed as the one Chrome and PhantomJS services provide, but this is good to know and would help with debugging. Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you guys happen to know the one for "browser logs" for chrome? i.e. webdriver.firefox.logfile but for Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

I believe logging for FireFox has to be enabled via a profile. Which needs to be base64 encoded.

Something along those lines is mentioned [in this bug raised against RemoteWebDriver](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=5478).

Any help?